# RQ-HUNO startup

Tags: c#, robotics

I am working with a RQ-HUNO Humanoid (Robot). I wish to perform actions that are present on the remote, from my C# program directly.

I know that it can be done using a Arduino and a IR-LED, but instead I want to test it with the USB mode.

I found a RobobuilderLib.dll but I am unable to understand the sequence of commands to be sent. I could not to find proper documentation relating the classes and functions of the library over the internet.

I wish somebody here will be able guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Read this file:  http://robosavvy.com/RoboSavvyPages/Robobuilder/RBC_over_Serial_Protocol_v1.13.pdf

It explains how the serial protocol works.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged (since the link could be turn up dead later). Could you make this answer more self-contained?

Comment: Link only answers are considered bad practice at stackoverflow. The link can become invalid and render your answer void.